# Converting SQL Server database to MS Access. Can't store images into MS Access database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I downloaded simple school management software built with C# using SQL Server. I exported its tables into a MS Access database. Also I made changes in code like `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, connection to OleDb. But in one form I can't store my image into access.

Here is the code:

```
private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_StudentFirstName.Text != "" && 
        txt_StudentMobileNo.Text != ""  && 
        cmb_Teacher.Text != "" && 
        img_Box.Image != null)
    {
        byte[] img = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Student (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, FatherID, DOB, 
                                                     DOR, Class, Course, Gender, Teacher, Address, 
                                                     EmailID, MobileNo, TotalFee, FeePaid, Balance, Image) 
                                VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @FatherName, @FatherID, @DOB,
                                        @DOR, @Class, @Course, @Gender, @Teacher, @Address,
                                        @EmailID, @MobileNo, @TotalFee, @FeePaid, @Balance, @Img)", con);

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_StudentFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_StudentLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", txt_StudentFatherName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherID", txt_StudentFatherID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Student_DOB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOR", Student_DOR.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", cmb_Class.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", cmb_Course.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cmb_Gender.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", cmb_Teacher.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_StudentAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", txt_StudentEmailID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", txt_StudentMobileNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalFee", cmb_CourseFee.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeePaid", txt_FeePaid.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", txt_Balance.Text);
        // byte[] yourPhoto = ();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", img);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");

        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide complete details with image !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you can't? What is the error? What type of field is Img in db? What type is img in c#?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column which is managing the image... Make sure that it is of type OLE .

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Why would you ever convert a working C# / SQL codebase to MS Access?

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ef838689-5484-4f23-bc3b-ce11c578c524/c-oledb-accessmdb-storing-and-retrieving-images. Embedding images (and other files) in table can quickly use up Access 2GB file size limit. Advise to just save file path string into text field.